# Undefined variable in PHP with class

Tags: php

I'm currently learning PHP on Codecademy and I got one error in their lesson, I don't know why. I get this error `Undefined variable: name (line 21)Woof, woof! !`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    class Dog {
        public $numLegs = 4;
        public $name;
        public function __construct($name){
            $this->name = $name;
        }
        public function bark(){
            return "Woof!";
        }
        public function greet(){
            return "Woof, woof! ".$name."!";
        }
    }
    $dog1 = new Dog("Barker");
    $dog2 = new Dog("Amigo");
    $dog1->bark();
    echo $dog2->greet();
?>
```

It's in this lesson http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-ZQQ64/0/8#. Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: it's a scope issue - `$name` in the `greet()` function is a local variable, which isn't defined; hence the warning. You probably need `$this->name` instead

Answer (score 5):

In order to refer to class fields you need to qualify the field names with `$this->`.  So this line:

```
return "Woof, woof! ".$name."!";
```

Should be this:

```
return "Woof, woof! ".$this->name."!";
```

Answer (score 3):

It tells you - on line 21, `$name` is not defined. Did you mean `$this->name`?